# Using Parent attributes (height, width) in child

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-ng-style

I'm using Material Dialog and need to resize my  to the edge of the dialog.
What I have (:
[image]
What I need (the entire upper part of the window is painted over, not just the strip) :

[image]

My solution doesn't work:

```
export class DialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() parent : HTMLElement;
  dialogProperties = [];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dialogProperties['height'] = this.parent.clientHeight;
    this.dialogProperties['width'] = this.parent.clientWidth;
  }
}
```

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch" style="height: 100%; position: relative">
  <div class="title" mat-dialog-title>
    <h1 class="header-mat-dialog" [ngStyle]="{'width': dialogProperties['width'], 'height': dialogProperties['height']}" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content" mat-card-content style="flex-grow: 1;">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom" fxFlex>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.header-mat-dialog {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #01A4B1;
  color: white;
}

.title {;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided it another way: set **padding: 0;** for **mat-dialog-container**.
ParentComponent:

```
openDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '100%',
      height: '80%',
      restoreFocus: false,
      panelClass: "ref"
    });
  }
```

Dialog:

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Dialog.scss

```
.ref .mat-dialog-container {
  padding: 0;
}
```

It remains to add margins for other elements.
[image]

PS: I found nice **box-shadow** style and use it for my title.

```
box-shadow:0 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
```